# Does find_by always return a match to the first of an array of conditions if possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I want to find a `Post` model whose `title` is "foo", but, if the post doesn't exist, "bar" and then "foobar".

For that I wrote this:

```
Post.find_by(title: %w(foo bar foobar))
```

It seems to be working fine now, but I'm not sure if the `find_by` method always finds the first value in the array of strings first.

When there are posts whose titles are `"foo"` and `"bar"`, does the code above always return the post with the title `"foo"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of alternatives doesn't matter. [Per the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by), `find_by`

> Finds the first record matching the specified conditions. There is no implied ordering so if order matters, you should specify it yourself.

If you want the posts in a particular order, you'll have to either

- add an `order` clause to the query, e.g.

  ```
  Post.order("case title when 'foo' then 0 when 'bar' then 1 when 'foobar' then 2 end").
  find_by(title: %w(foo bar foobar))
  ```

  Tested in MySQL; not sure about how widespread that syntax is but at least something similar should be available in any SQL database.

  You might need to build the `order` clause dynamically. From ironsand's solution in the comments:

  ```
  titles = %w(foo bar foobar)
  order_sql = "case #{titles.map.with_index { |title, i| "when '#{title}' then #{i}" }.join ' ' } end"
  Post.order(order_sql).find_by(title: titles)
  ```
- query all the posts and sort them afterwards

  ```
  Post.all.sort_by { |post| %w(foo bar foobar).index post.title }.first
  ```

  This will be slow for a large number of posts, so whether it's useful probably depends on whether you can start with something more specific than `Post.all`.

Comment: `find_by` return at most one record so the "sort the Posts afterwards" is just a complicated way of raising a NoMethodError. The `ORDER BY CASE...` approach OTOH should work and work with any RDBMS.

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE` might quickly become unusable when there are 20+ dynamic titles. One should either build the `order` clause dynamically or use `Post.where(title: titles).sort_by`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with the way `ORDER BY CASE`. To simplify the conditional string I wrote like `titles.map.with_index{|title, i| "when '#{title}' then #{i} "}.join`.

Comment: Oops, didn't finish my thought on the in-memory option. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

For this

```
Post.find_by(title: %w(foo bar foobar))
```

the sql query run as

```
SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."title" IN ('foo', 'bar', 'foobar') LIMIT 1
```

the query contains a limit constraint, so you will get only one record eventhough the condition satisfies.

You should use where query to get all recors

```
Post.where(title: %w(foo bar foobar))
```